# Is it possible to open a file allowing another processes to delete this file?

Tags: windows, go

It seems the default `os.Open` call allows another processes to write the opened file, but not to delete it. Is it possible to enable deletion as well? In .NET this can be done using `FileShare.Delete` flag, is there any analog in Go?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19875329

Comment: I'm only guessing here - but since this is the way files work in Unix, and since Go is a) unix centric and b) tries to be portable and not have custom per-OS methods or flags - there isn't such an option. I would look in the syscall package that lets you run low level per os syscalls, and is usually used by higher level library code.

Comment: It appears the windows syscall package indeed has the notion of a SHARE_DELETE mode when opening files. See http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/ztypes_windows.go#L93 . However, keep in mind that doing this in a place that is is not windows specific (i.e. a file not ending with _windows.go) will result in non portable code.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, I don't know much about nix. Doesn't it allow to let another processes remove the currently opened file?

Comment: @user626528 deleting is called "unlinking" in Unix-ish, meaning removing one link from a path or name to the actual data on the disk (many can be created). These are separate in Unix. Once a file doesn't have any links to it, it disappears. This means that you can delete an open file of a running process, but apart from the path, it still exists until this process exits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.Open` will get you a file descriptor with flag `O_RDONLY` set; that means read only. You can specify your own flag by using `os.OpenFile`

```
O_RDONLY int = syscall.O_RDONLY // open the file read-only.
O_WRONLY int = syscall.O_WRONLY // open the file write-only.
O_RDWR   int = syscall.O_RDWR   // open the file read-write.
O_APPEND int = syscall.O_APPEND // append data to the file when writing.
O_CREATE int = syscall.O_CREAT  // create a new file if none exists.
O_EXCL   int = syscall.O_EXCL   // used with O_CREATE, file must not exist
O_SYNC   int = syscall.O_SYNC   // open for synchronous I/O.
O_TRUNC  int = syscall.O_TRUNC  // if possible, truncate file when opened.
```

None of these modes, however, will allow you to have multiple writers on a single file. You can share the file descriptor by `exec`-ing or `fork`-ing but naively writing to the file from both processes will result in the OS deciding how to synchronise those writes -- which is almost never what you want.

Deleting a file while a process has a FD on it doesn't matter on unix-like systems. I'll go ahead and assume Windows won't like that, though.

*Edit given the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) tag and @Not_a_Golfer's excellent observations:*

You should be able to pass `syscall.FILE_SHARE_DELETE` as a flag to `os.OpenFile` on Windows, if that is what solves your problem.

If you need to combine several flags you can do so by or-ing them together:

```
syscall.FILE_SHARE_DELETE | syscall.SOME_OTHER_FLAG | syscall.AND_A_THIRD_FLAG
```

(note, however, that it's up to you to build a coherent flag)

Comment: see my comments to OP, it's possible in Windows but not the default setting, as far as I can tell by reading the OS-specific file opening code in the std library.

Comment: I'd add this if this code should live beyond the original author's personal computer, stuff like this should be done inside a windows only file (ending with _windows.go), while keeping support for the same functionality for other targets. The syscall package is the best example for that.