# Did the behaviour of deleted files open with FileShare.Delete change on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

We have been using the following code for several years.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a file and returns an exclusive handle. The file is deleted as soon as the handle is released.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The name of the file to create</param>
    /// <returns>A FileStream backed by an exclusive handle</returns>
    /// <remarks>If another process attempts to open this file, they will recieve an UnauthorizedAccessException</remarks>
    public static System.IO.FileStream OpenAsLock(string path)
    {
        var stream = TranslateIOExceptions(() => System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.Delete));
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        return stream;
    }
```

From memory, this code *used* to leave a file in place until the FileStream was closed. The technique was used as part of a cooperative concurrency lock.

I found a number of other questions which make me think the behavior used to be as the comment describes: the file stays in place until the returned filestream is closed.

[Will we ever be able to delete an open file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202329/will-we-ever-be-able-to-delete-an-open-file-in-windows)

[Can using FileShare.Delete cause a UnauthorizedAccessException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875329/can-using-fileshare-delete-cause-a-unauthorizedaccessexception)

However, as part of an investigation, I've discovered Windows does not behave this way. Instead, the file is deleted as soon as the call to File.Delete is made. I also tried to reproduce the error Hans suggested would occur in the above link without success.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File.Open("test", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete);
        File.Delete("test");
        File.WriteAllText("test", "hello world");
        Console.Write(File.ReadAllText("test"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the unit test we had which might have caught this change in behavior was not configured correctly to run nightly in our environment, so I can't be certain if it ever ran green.

Was this a real change in behavior? Do we know when it happened? Was it intentional (documented)?

Comment: The behavior changed in recent releases of Windows 10 -- without notice AFAIK. `DeleteFileW` now tries to use [POSIX semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex) if the filesystem supports it. NTFS does. After setting the delete disposition with POSIX semantics, the file is unlinked as soon as `DeleteFileW` closes its handle. Existing opens, which must have shared delete access, can continue to access the file, but they cannot unset the delete disposition, unlike the classic Windows delete semantics.

Comment: If you want the classic behavior that leaves the file linked in the directory until the last handle is closed, you can manually call `SetFileInformationByHandle` : `FileDispositionInfo`.

Comment: Let me reiterate that existing opens must share delete access in order to delete or rename a file, regardless of the delete semantics, so Windows is still very different from POSIX systems. Most applications share read/execute and write/append access on their open files, but they do not share delete/rename access.

Comment: @ErykSun, do you know which Windows 10 version and build, specifically, made deletion synchronous, and what Windows Server version that corresponds to? eisenpony's answer suggests version `1909`, build `18363.657`, but a user just commented at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375 that they still see asynchronous behavior as of `18363.1316`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Eryk for the tip.

It turned out we did have several unit tests in place that would have caught this change in behavior, including tests that explicitly test for this behavior. I suspect those were added while investigating this strange behavior in the first place.

The unit tests had not raised the alarm yet because our test machine was running an older build of Windows 10 than my dev machine.

- Build 17134.1304 definitely has the old behavior.
- Build 18363.657 definitely has the new behavior.

I reviewed the [list of build releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/) and, unfortunately, there were over two dozen releases between these two versions. However, I am very suspicious of this "Improvement and fix" listed as part of [build 17763.832, available Oct 15, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520062/windows-10-update-kb4520062)

> Addresses an issue in which files that are stored in a Cluster Shared
>   Volume (CSV) with an alternate data stream are still present after you
>   try to delete them. You may also receive an "access is denied" message
>   on the next try to access or delete the files.

I'm not sure why a change specific to CSV affects my system, but the description matches exactly the change I am seeing.

---

In regards to the specific code, it turned out the return "FileStream" was never used in our code. Instead, we relied on the IDisposable interface, closing the stream when the "critical section" was complete, and unlocking the shared file.

Technically a breaking change, I now do the following:

1. Create the lock file with an exclusive handle
2. Return a new object that implements IDisposable
3. Wait until the disposable object is disposed, then close the stream and **try** to delete the file

```
// ...
    public static IDisposable OpenAsLock(string path)
    {
        var stream = TranslateIOExceptions(() => System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None));
        return new FileBasedLock(stream, path);
    }
// ...

internal class FileBasedLock : IDisposable
{
    public FileBasedLock(FileStream stream, string path)
    {
        Stream = stream ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        Path = path ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
    }

    public FileStream Stream { get; }
    public string Path { get; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stream.Close();
        try { File.Delete(Path); }
        catch (IOException) { }
    }
}
```